# How can I rotate a container layout?

Tags: java, android

I have a container layout. It have inside an `ImageView` and a `TextView` I want to rotate the container layout. I have the code to a ImageView now I tried to rotate the container layout using the same logic but I can make it work is the code okay or what I'm missing?

or there it other way to rotate an `ImageView` and a `TextView` together?

```
    public class ruleta4F extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ImageView imageRoulette;
        private  FrameLayout mainView;
        TextView ruletaNombre;
        TextView castigo1,castigo2,castigo3,castigo4;
        TextView nombreRuleta4;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ruleta4_f);
            imageRoulette = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_roulette);
            mainView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
            /////////////////get data
            ruletaNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
            String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("namer");
            ruletaNombre.setText(name);

            castigo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            String sc1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("sc1");
            castigo1.setText(sc1);

            castigo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            String sc2= getIntent().getStringExtra("sc2");
            castigo2.setText(sc2);

            castigo3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
            String sc3= getIntent().getStringExtra("sc3");
            castigo3.setText(sc3);

            castigo4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            String sc4= getIntent().getStringExtra("sc4");
            castigo4.setText(sc4);
        }
 public void actionRoulette(View view) {

 int corner = 360/38; // corner for point
            int randPosition = corner * new Random().nextInt(38); 
            int MIN = 5; // min rotation
            int MAX = 9; // max rotation
            long TIME_IN_WHEEL = 1000;  // time in one rotation
            int randRotation = MIN + new Random().nextInt(MAX-MIN); // random rotation
            int truePosition =  randRotation * 360 + randPosition;
            long totalTime = TIME_IN_WHEEL * randRotation + (TIME_IN_WHEEL/360) * randPosition;

            Log.d("ROULETTE_ACTION","randPosition : " + randPosition
                    + " randRotation : " + randRotation
                    + " totalTime : " + totalTime
                    + " truePosition : " + truePosition);

            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"rotation",0f,(float)truePosition);
            animator.setDuration(totalTime);
            animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                    mainView.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    mainView.setEnabled(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
            animator.start();

        }

}
```

Comment: Your animation code works just fine for me. I would point out, though, that you're setting the `ObjectAnimator` on `view`, which is the method parameter for `actionRoulette()`. On which `View` do you have `actionRoulette` set as the `onClick` attribute? Did you mean to set the `ObjectAnimator` on `mainView` instead?

Comment: I had the actionRoulette onClick on imageView and i was rotation the image now i want set objectAnimatios on mainView. Thanks